# Is it possible to switch theme on mobile device in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am from wordpress background, I am looking into drupal CMS. Can you switch themes according to the device. if the site is viewed from a mobile browser is it possible to switch to a mobile theme and if viewed from desktop vice versa?

Comment: Have a look at this module https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey

Comment: thank you! i found similar posts but the last updated date was 2006, this link you provided is much more recent. that's a great link! thank you!